Invalid credentails getting passed via Jmeter test run
i am running a test via Jmeter for multiple users at once with only one is valid via csv config,but the all the threads are getting passed. it should show error when it clicks on login for rest invalid user details. Can anyone suggest why its happening and how to fix it.
note - i have recorded the scenario to test

JMeter considers Sampler successful if it returns HTTP status code below 400.
If the system under test returns HTTP status 200 on login attempt with incorrect credentials JMeter won't detect the error, you will need to add a Response Assertion and specify your custom pass/fail criteria there, i.e. presence of "Welcome" text or absence of "Login" text or something like this.
